# How to manage make workflows / builds where the installation source's existence might change and differ from application folders?

Tags: makefile, build

How to manage make workflows / builds where the installation source's state might change?

This example comes from OpenBSD:
https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/ports.html#PortsInstall. But might/should exist on other systems as well.

Notice that here we:

1. Have the source and build workflows in a folder (call this **folder_srcs**).
2. Build it and install the software to a different folder (e.g., /usr/local, call this place **folder_apps**).

Consider that software in **folder_apps** becomes outdated or varied in dependencies later on when we have used the system for a while and added new software. We might also upgrade the sources at **folder_srcs** over time via system updates etc. Then it's possible that the software available in **folder_apps** does not correspond to software in **folder_srcs**. This means e.g. that:

**folder_apps**:

- eventually has old things that are not used
- might eventually have things that have become non-functional or non-upgradeable

**folder_srcs**:

- cannot build older software that might be required in order to operate some software that depended on an earlier "state" of **folder_apps**.

Do some OSes have measures against this kind of phenomenon? What?

How can developers manage these phenomena?